# dis/trust or (dis)trust?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

One should know that trust and distrust are very crucial for any relationship.

If we want to turn "trust and distrust" into one single word, which of the following is a better choice? What is such kind of playing with words called?

1. One should know that **dis/trust** is very crucial for any relationship.
2. One should know that **(dis)trust** is very crucial for any relationship.

Comment: Is distrust crucial for a relationship? It seems to me that distrust is undesirable and could be destructive for a relationship.

Comment: What you want to do is create something that is not a single word, but more like a marketing slogan, so you can style it to look however you want. [dis]trust, or whatever, it will never be a proper word.

Comment: Neither of your sentences have combined them into a single word. Not only does the concept of trust includes the idea of distrust, but nobody would find the idea of *distrust* being very crucial to a relationship to be meaningful. Therefore, simply say *trust*.

Comment: Dis, is a [prefix](https://blog.allaboutlearningpress.com/prefixes/) in this case. A slash implies that you have two alternatives to the word and should be used: distrust/trust therefore the brackets (or as @Tymek suggested, square brackets) are more appropriate. As everyone else has mentioned above though, the technique doesn't really work for the sentence you have provided.

Comment: and thus [sbeve] came into live